# DropdownList is not showing the default value or the selected value in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have implemented a dropdown list using HTML helpers in a form.I have  provided a default value to the dropdownlist .The dropdownlist is populated using a viewModel.

This is my code for the DDl.

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "Select a Genre", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre)
</div>
```

The model for the form is as shown below

```
public class GigFormViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FutureDate]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidTime]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte Genre { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public DateTime GetDateTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));
    }
}
```

Now,in the controller , I am populating the DDl.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new GigFormViewModel
    {
        Genres = _dbContext.Genres.ToList()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This is the Genre model

```
public class Genre
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the HTML for the dropdownlist.

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Genre">Genre</label>
       <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The 
       field Genre must be a number." data-val-required="The Genre field is 
            required." id="Genre" name="Genre">
         <option value="">Select a Genre</option>
         <option value="1">Jazz</option>
         <option value="2">Blues</option>
         <option value="3">Rock</option>
         <option value="4">Country</option>
      </select>
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Genre" data- 
      valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </div>
```

With the above code in place , the DDl list is getting populated.But, the selected value is not showing in DDL nor is the default value.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: could u plz show your `Genre` model that you specified in `IEnumerable<Genre>`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the Genre model. Please look through.

Comment: its work well on my side. are you able to view options in drop down list?

Comment: Yes, I am able to view the options. When an option is selected , that does not show up as selected. Its basically blank every time.

Comment: I would add a pic to show u what I am seeing but i am not allowed to.

Comment: try to inspect dropdownlist in browser and copy and add the rendered html to your question

Comment: I have added the HTML for the dropdownlist in the edited question.Please look through,

Comment: I also compared your posted html for dropdownlistfor and my side html for dropdownlistfor but i didn't found any difference between both...

Comment: try to hit `Ctrl + F5` several times. i think your browser render cache page.

Comment: The default and selected value is displaying when I tried with above . See the below links. https://i.imgur.com/CNSFrdV.png
https://i.imgur.com/33BMs1h.png

Comment: Thanks for the help.Since it was working for u folks without my user defined CSS, I figured it out. I had given some padding to the form-control class which for some reason was creating an issue. The values were getting selected but were not showing up in the dropdown list because of the padding, I suppose. 

So, basically , the padding pushed down the values which were to be shown in the DDL.